# Move multiple files in same directory without typing directory name each time (Linux)

Tags: linux

I have a directory dir with files a, b, c, and I want to move them

```
mv dir/a dir/b dir/c ...
```

is the standard way to do it. Is there a shortcut to avoid typing dir/ multiple times? Perhaps like so:

```
mv dir/(a, b, c) ...
```

Comment: Probably the more typical technique is: `cd dir; mv a b c ../....`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's quite similar to what you guessed: `mv dir/{a,b,c} dest`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to do the following

```
mv dir/{a.out, b.out, c.out} /path/to/newdirectory/
```

You just need to use curly braces instead of parenthesis.